# Unity is completely theme less with nautilus?

Tags: unity, nautilus, gnome, themes

after installing gnome3-shell unity is completely theme less(icon,nautilus,windows manager,panel) and after several gnome updates gnome is also theme less(icon,nautilus only)..

Help me to restore theme to unity and gnome 3...

```
terminal:~$ gnome-settings-daemon
 ** (gnome-settings-daemon:3881): WARNING **: Ignoring unknown module 'org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.gconf' [1305719379,000,xklavier.c:xkl_engine_start_listen/]
The backend does not require manual layout management - but it is provided by the application `menu_proxy_module_load':
gnome-settings-daemon: undefined symbol: menu_proxy_module_load (gnome-settings-daemon:3881):
Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to load type module: (null) Segmentation fault But sudo gnome-settings-daemon enable the theme in gnome3 but disable tapping in synaptics device
```

Answer (score 1):

> Help me to restore theme to unity and gnome 3... :(( :((

- This is not possible. In Ubuntu 11.04 Gnome/Unity is based on gtk2, while gnome3 is based on gtk3. So you either choose gnome/unity or gnome3.
- If you installed gnome3 via this ppa https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3, you should be able to choose a gnome3 session in the GDM login screen.
- If you want pure unity back, you can remove the Gnome 3 PPA and everything it installed with:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
  sudo ppa-purge:gnome3-team/gnome3
  ```